# Append multiple CharW code in Ms word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to replace some characters into Unicode character in ms word.

So, I have this string: `2437,2478,2479`. I would like to convert this into `CharW(2437) & CharW(2478) & CharW(2479)`

I tried to split it with an array and want to achieve my goal by the following code:

```
SplitChar = "2437,2478,2479"
Dim test
SplitChar2 = Split(SplitChar, ",")

For j = 0 To UBound(SplitChar2)
   ' What I Actually need to do here for appending in `test`
Next
```

When I will call `test` it should be returned `CharW(2437) & CharW(2478) & CharW(2479)`

Is it possible by ms word VBA?
Thanks.

Comment: `test = test & ChrW$(CLng(SplitChar2(j)))`

Comment: Great. Thank you so much, my friend. I was trying in PHP way `test .=`